# CakePHP/PHPUnit: Testing a redirect - Location header does not seem to be set correctly

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

When writing a cake php controller tests withing a mock object the Location header doesnt seem to be set. From looking at the code I know for a fact that redirect is being called with the correct value. What am I doing wrong here?

Login Code:

```
    if (!$this->Auth->login()) {
        ...
        echo "Redirect reached.\n";
        $this->redirect('/users/login');
    }
```

Test:

```
public function testLoginFailedRedirectsToLogin() {
    $users = $this->generate('Users', array(
        'components' => array('Session'=>array('setFlash'))));
    $users->Session
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('setFlash');
    $users->response
        ->expects($this->once())
        ->method('header')
        ->with('Location', '/users/login');

    $data = array('Users' => array(
            'username' => 'bad-user',
            'password' => 'infinet',
            'remember_me' => false,
        ));
    $this->testAction('/users/login',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post'));
    var_dump($this->headers['Location']);
    $this->assertEqual($this->headers['Location'], '/users/login');
}
```

Output:

```
Redirect reached.
string(74) "http://localhost/home/nishant/projects/atp/1/.build/tmp/27784/app/Console/"
...

1) LoginTest::testLoginFailedRedirectsToLogin
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'/users/login'
+'http://localhost/home/nishant/projects/atp/1/.build/tmp/27784/app/Console/
```

If I remove the assertEqual the redirect's expect fails as well.

Answer (score -1):

Should be

```
return $this->redirect('/users/login');
```

Comment: thanks, mromagnoli, but I can't remember the context of this question - It doesn't look like a very good question all after reviewing it all these months later